# free(): double free detected in tcache 2 while deleting dynamic array

Tags: c++, arrays, c-strings

I am trying to read a .txt file and print the lines, while using only c-style string.

```
int main(int argc, char * argv[]){
   ...

   size_t size = 2;
   char* line = new char[size];
   char c;
   while (file.get(c)) {
       if(c != '\n'){
          line[size - 2] = c;
          char* temp = new char[size + 1];
          memcpy(temp, line, size * sizeof(char));
          delete[] line;
          line = temp;
          delete[] temp;
          size++;
        } else{
           line[size - 1] = '\n';
           cout << line << endl;
           delete [] line;
           size = 2;
           line = new char[size];
        }
   }
...
}
```

I am getting the error `free(): double free detected in tcache 2`. What is the problem and how can fix it?

Comment: Don't `delete[] temp`...

Comment: When you used the debugger following the execution from one code line to another, did you notice how many times `delete` called in comparison with number of `new` calls?

Comment: @tkausl Don't I have to delete all the space, thar I have allocated? Why do I have to delete `line` and not `temp`?

Comment: Because you assign it to `line` and keep using it, so you can't delete it.

Comment: *how can fix it?* -- You fix it by using `std::string` and `std::vector<std::string>` instead of low-level calls to `new[]` and `delete[]`.  Modern C++ user-programs that have `new[]` and `delete[]` are now considered code smells.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie @PaulMcKenzie is a `vector<char>` considered a c-style string as well or only char arrays?

Comment: A `std::vector<char>` is basically a dynamic array of `char` that has convenient member functions.  You get to the underlying data by using the vector's `data()` method.  So you're not losing anything, and gaining safety by using `std::vector<char>` over `new[]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am getting the error free(): double free detected in tcache 2. What
> is the problem and how can fix it?

By understanding the error in this code:

```
char* temp = new char[size + 1];
memcpy(temp, line, size * sizeof(char));
delete[] line;
line = temp;
delete[] temp;
```

The important thing to remember is that `temp` and `line` are *pointers to an array of chars*; that is they can *refer* to an array but they do not (by themselves) represent *copies* of the array.  So:

```
// sets (line) to a memory address where (size) bytes have been
// made available for you to use.  Let's assume (line) gets set to
// 0x11223344
char* line = new char[size];

[...]

// sets (temp) to the memory address where (size+1) bytes have been
// made available for you to use.  For the sake of the exmaple, 
// let's assume (temp) gets set here to memory-address 0x12345678.
char* temp = new char[size + 1];

// Copies (size) bytes from (line) (aka starting at  memory-address 0x11223344)
// to (temp) (aka starting at memory-address 0x12345678)  
memcpy(temp, line, size * sizeof(char));

// tells the heap that you no longer need the byte-array starting at 0x11223344.
// After this delete[] returns, the heap is allowed to reuse those
// bytes for other (unrelated) things, so you are no longer allowed to 
// read or write that memory region!
delete[] line;

// Sets the value of the (line) pointer to point to 0x12345678 instead.
line = temp;

// tells the heap that you no longer need the bytes starting at 0x12345678.
// After this delete[] returns, the heap is allowed to use those
// bytes for other (unrelated) things, so you are no longer allowed to 
// read or write that memory region!    
delete[] temp;

// Note that at this point, (line) is still pointing to 0x1234568, *but*
// you are no longer allowed to use the memory at that address!
// This is a problem, because on the next iteration of your while-loop,
// you are going to write to either line[size-2] or line[size-1]; either
// either way you are writing to freed memory, which will invoke 
// undefined behavior and cause problems for you.
```

So, how to fix this?  As suggested in the comments, the best way to fix it would be to avoid `new` and `delete[]` entirely, and stick to using `std::string` instead, since that would avoid all the usual problems with dangling pointers, use-after-free, uninitialized-memory-reads, unterminated strings, etc.

If you *must* use `new` and `delete[]`, however (e.g. because that's the rules of the assignment), then you need to keep track of the lifetime of each of your heap allocations; in this case, that means realizing that when you set `line = temp;`, that means that `line` is now pointing to the *same* array `temp` is pointing to, and since your code wants to use that array in the future, you shouldn't call `delete[] temp;` as that deletes the heap-allocation that `line` was pointing to, and leaves `line` as a dangling-pointer (i.e. pointing to memory you are no longer permitted to use).

Comment: Btw I find it helpful when dealing with pointer-problems to temporarily insert lines like `printf("At line number %i, temp=%p line=%p\n", __LINE__, temp, line)`; that way you can see printed the actual memory-locations that the pointers are pointing to, which makes it easier to understand what is going on.